# Difference between projection and component of a vector in product?

Tags: forces, vectors, vector-fields

This is a very basic question about dot products or scalar products:-

If I want to move a block and I apply a force parallel to displacement, the block will move and some work will be done. So in the formula will be $W= F\cdot S$, here we won't calculate the force mg of the block but the force we applied (the parallel force).

Now let's say that the force is not parallel and is at [some angle from the horizontal](https://images.app.goo.gl/TSHRHFsSaWggWqqE7)

So in this case the work done will be the projection of the force $F_1$ on the $x$ axis, because that is how dot products are defined (As Projections). 
But can't we say that the block moved due to its horizontal component $F_1\cos(\theta)$ and the answer would be same. And obviously we won't count $F_1\sin(\theta)$ as the work is not done by it.

So why do we say projection and not component in dot or vector product ?

Comment: The two are the same, and many (most?) instructors of introductory mechanics courses do use "component" and never use "projection".  Your instructor does it differently.  Why don't you ask him/her?  I suspect the answer will be "Oh, that's just my habit.".  Or maybe "I like the geometrical picture that projections have."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out, the projection and component actually refers to the same thing. To solve a problem like this it useful to introduce a coordinate system, as you mentioned yourself you project onto the x-axis. As soon as you introduce a coordinate system you can talk about the $\textit{components}$ of some vector. E.g $\vec{F} = F_1 \cos(\theta)\hat{x} + F_1 \sin(\theta) \hat{y}$ and $\vec{S} = S_1 \hat{x}$ if the box in your example is constrained to move horizontally. Here the components of the vectors are the $\textit{projections}$ of the vectors onto the coordinate axis. With this construct you calculate the dot product as $W = \vec{F} \cdot\vec{S} = F_1\cos(\theta) S_1$.

However it is not needed to introduce a coordinate system and writing the vectors by their  components and then applying the rules for dot product. The dot product is defined in a coordinate independent way as a projection. So your question is just a matter of terminology. A $\textit{component}$ of a vector along some axis is the $\textit{projection}$ of the vector along that axis and in this sense projection is the more fundamental thing.

Answer (score 1):

*Projection* and *component* mean the same thing in this context.

Let me however note that a *force* is a part of the physical reality, existing in the world (at least for the purposes of mechanics), whereas a *projection* is a mathematical object/construct. From this point of view the work is done by the force (or by its component), but not by the projection.